# Selecting first in a subset

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a DOM like this;

```
<li></li>
<li class="this"></li>
<li class="this"></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li class="this"></li>
<li class="this"></li>
<li class="this"></li>
<li></li>
<li class="this"></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
```

I would only like to select the first li within each series of consecutive `this`es.

So, if I would for instance apply a `.addClass("that")` to the objects of this selector, the resulting DOM would look like so;

```
<li></li>
<li class="this that"></li>
<li class="this"></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li class="this that"></li>
<li class="this"></li>
<li class="this"></li>
<li></li>
<li class="this that"></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
```

What would be the most efficient way of achieving such an effect? I cannot add or remove any elements in the DOM (so for instance wrapping the consecutive series in their own wrapper divs is not possible).

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Will this work?

```
$("li:not(.this) + .this").addClass('that');
```

EDIT: If the first item is of class `this`, that won't work, you'll need this (if it applies):

```
$("li:not(.this) + .this, .this:first-of-type").addClass('that');
```

Comment: I have no idea how that works, but it does indeed seem to work! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @EmphramStavanger: `+` means adjacent elements, selecting the one on the right hand :) And you're welcome! (I like this type of query very much. CSS3 is great.)

Comment: @EmphramStavanger: Oh, I just noticed a slight problem. See my edit.

Comment: Oh, nice catch! I hadn't even thought of the first element being a `this`, but it sure is possible, awesome

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.this').each(function(){
    if($(this).prev().hasClass('this')==false){
        $(this).addClass('that');
    }
});
```

loop through all elements with the class `this` and if its previous sibling doesn't have a the same class then add `that` to it